# Notation involving the set of germs

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a sheaf on a topological space and let $\mathcal{F}_p$ denote the set of germs of $\mathcal{F}$ at $p$.

I want to show that the map of sets $$ \mathcal{F}(U) \to \prod_{p \in U} \mathcal{F}_p $$

is injective.

This may be silly,  but I am not sure how to interpret $$\prod_{p \in U} \mathcal{F}_p$$

What is the exact meaning of this notation?

Comment: The $\mathscr{F}_p$ are groups. Take the direct product of those groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in previous answers the stalk at a point $p$ is defined as $\mathrm{colim}_{V\ni p}\mathscr{F}(V)$, but there is a less abstract version of this. As stalk at point $p$ is the collection of germs:= $(f,U)$ meaning $f\in \mathscr{F}(U)$ with an identification of germs:= $(f,U)=(g,V)$ if there exists $W\subset U,V$ such that $f|_{W}=g|_{W}$. In other words
$$
\mathscr{F}_p = \{(f,U)|p\in U, f\in \mathscr{F}(U)\}/\sim
$$
where $\sim$ is the relation defined above. Now to understand the map $\mathscr{F}(U)\to \prod_{p\in U}\mathscr{F}_p$, consider $f\in \mathscr{F}(U)$, then $(f,U)$ is a germ on every point of $U$. In other words $U$ is a neighborhood of every point $p$ in $U$. So the map is defined as
$$
f\mapsto\Big((f,U)_{p_1}, (f,U)_{p_2}, \cdots\Big)
$$
(here I am assuming for simplicity that the product is countable but that's just so you can see what is happening more clearly). The notation $(f,U)_{p_i}$ meaning the equivalence class of the germ $(f,U)$ as a member of the stalk $\mathscr{F}_{{p}_i}$. Now if $f,g$ have the same image under this map, this means the germs $(f,U)$ and $(g,U)$ are equivalent in each stalk. So $f=g$ and the map is injective.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't explicitly state what $\newcommand{\FF}{\mathcal{F}}\FF$ is a sheaf of, but regardless, each $\FF_p$ is an object in some category, and $\prod_{p \in U} \FF_p$ is the [categorical product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_%28category_theory%29) of the $\FF_p$ in this category.

So, for example:

- If $\FF$ is a sheaf of sets, then the product is the Cartesian product of sets.
- If $\FF$ is a sheaf of groups or rings or modules, the product is direct product.
- If $\FF$ is a sheaf of topological spaces, the product is the Cartesian product with the product topology.

The stalk $\FF_p$ itself comes from another categorical construction: $\FF_p = \operatorname{colim}_{V \ni p} \FF(V)$, where the colimit is a filtered colimit over the system of open neighborhoods of $p$ with respect to inclusion. (Filtered colimits are often called "direct limits", but this is unfortunate terminology — they're colimits, not limits.)

In the cases mentioned above, this is essentially a "union with gluing": an element of the stalk is an element of any $\FF(V)$, and we identify elements of $\FF(V_1)$ and $\FF(V_2)$ if their restrictions to some open neighborhood $W \subseteq V_1 \cap V_2$ are equal.

Answer (score 0):

The notation $\prod_{p\in U}\mathcal{F}_p$ denotes the cartesian product of the sets $\mathcal{F}_p$ for every point $p\in U$.  Explicitly, an element of $\prod_{p\in U}\mathcal{F}_p$ is a function $s$ with domain $U$ such that for each $p\in U$, $s(p)$ is an element of the set $\mathcal{F}_p$.